# Understanding quick sort algorithm and its worst case

Tags: c, quicksort

i think i know quick sort algorithm.But i need help in figuring out its worst case.

Lets look at the below quicksort code---->

```
void quicksort(int arr[],int low,int high) //low and high are pased from main()
{
 int m;
 if(low<high)
 {
  m=partition(arr,low,high);
  quicksort(arr,low,m-1);
  quicksort(arr,m+1,high);
  }
}
int partition(int arr[],int low,int high)
{
 int pivot=arr[low],i=low,j=high;
 while(i<j)
 {
  while((arr[i]<=pivot)&&(i<=high))
  i++;
  while(arr[j]>pivot)
  j--;
  if(i<j)
  swap(arr,i,j);               //swaps arr[i]and arr[j]
 }
  swap(arr,low,j);             //swaps arr[low] and arr[j]
  return j;
}
```

I am not writing the definition of swap function here as it is self explanatory.

Now lets trace the above code for arr 1 2 3 4 5

```
0   4    0         partion swaps 1 with 1 and returns 0 which is assigned to m
low high m     
__________________________
0   0    *         
0   4    0
low high m
___________________________
0   0    * 
1   4    1         partition swaps 2 with 2
0   4    0
low high m
____________________________
2   4    2         partition swaps 3 with 3
1   4    1
0   4    0
low high m
____________________________
2   1    * 
2   4    2         
1   4    1
0   4    0
low high m
______________________________
3   4    3            partition swaps 4 with 4
2   4    2
1   4    1
0   4    0
low high m
________________________________
3   2    *
3   4    3
2   4    2
1   4    1
0   4    0
low high m
_________________________________
4   4    *
3   4    3
2   4    2
1   4    1
0   4    0
low high m
_________________________________
Stack empty
low high m
```

ques1.Is my understanding of quicksort correct?

ques2.In worst case , quicksort does n-1+n-2+.....+1 comparisons.How?

Here,i think it would have n+2 comparisons...instead of n-1.
Partition would check

```
(1<=1,i++),(5>1,j--),
(2<=1,don't incr i),(4>1,j--),
(3>1,j--),
(2>1,j--),
(1>1,don't incr j)
```

total 7 i.e (n+2) comparisons

Answer (score 1):

With algorithm you have shown, the pivot is always selected as the first element of the array.  Just suppose you get an already ordered array, in that case the pivot will go to the first element (as it was) after comparing with it `n-1` elements, and you will call quicksort recursively for two arrays, the first with the elements before the pivot (0 elements, an empty array) and the other with all elements after the pivot (n-1 elements).  In that case, you'll get a recursive call to quicksort with an array of `n-1` elements, that happens to be ordered again, and the first element (the new pivot) is going to produce an array of 0 elements (before the pivot), the pivot, and an array of `n-2` elements.  Do you follow the sequence?

As the worst case in your code happens precisely with an already ordered array, normally quicksort just gets the element in the middle as the pivot, so in that case it doesn't do anything also, but degenerating in half size arrays each time (well half the size minus one --the pivot).

In the case you get a degenerated situation like the previous, you get n comparisons in the first pass, then n-1 comparisons, then n-2, for a total of n*(n+1)/2 total of comparisons, and in the case you divide by two each time, you get n comparisons each pass for a total of log_2(n) passes, what makes a total of n*log_2(n) comparisons.  Suppose n=1000000, that makes 1000001000000/2 = 200000500000 comparisons in the first case, in front of 20*1000000 = 20000000 (a lot less)

Comment: in that case the pivot will go to the first element (as it was) after comparing with it n-1 elements,
I am not getting this how n-1 elements

Comment: you always get all n elements compared at each pass, but in the degenerated case you get n passes, for log_2(n) passes on the other case.

Comment: in last part of my post i have shown that comparisons are n+2 and not n-1

Comment: in each pass, for an array of n elements you compare n-1 elements against the pivot, so you make n-1 comparisons at all.  In case you have divided the array in subarrays you make each subarray (of length n_i) n_i-1 comparisons, for a total of $\sum_{i=0}^{i < k}n_i-1  = n - k $ comparisons (k is the number of partitions you have for the original array in pass l.  The worst case is when you allways get the pivot in one extremum, as then you don't get the array partitioned in the middle.  In that case you get n passes.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong what you have done.  I only say that for an array of length n_i, you compare all the elements (except the pivot) with it, so you must make n_i - 1 comparisons at all.  if you make more, your are doing unnecessary comparisons. don't you?

Comment: suppose you have the array 1 2 3 4 and you compare 1 with 2, then 1 with 3 and then 1 with 4... you have made three comparisons... not five.

Comment: at first you don't swap 1 with 1, as both indexes point to element 0, they don't get swapped (i must be < j, not <=) Indeed you never do a swap, as always i and j point to the same element (the pivot)